# Python - removing characters from a list

Tags: python, list

I have list of elements like this:

```
['1:{test}', '2:{test}', '4:{1989}', '9:{test}', '']
```

My question is:

How can I remove specific characters from the elements of this list ?

As a result I want to have :

```
['test', 'test', '1989', 'test', '']
```

Any suggestions, solutions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\{(.*)\}', '1:{test}')
['test']
```

Just make a loop with it:

```
[(re.findall(r'\{(.*)\}', i) or [''])[0] for i in your_list]
```

or maybe:

```
[''.join(re.findall(r'\{(.*)\}', i)) for i in your_list]
```

Comment: Thanks, I read about regular expressions, and I like your anwser.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, like so:

```
import re

s = re.compile("\d+:{(.*)}")

data = ['1:{test}', '2:{test}', '4:{1989}', '9:{test}', '']

result = [s.match(d).group(1) if s.match(d) else d for d in data]
```

results in

```
['test', 'test', '1989', 'test', '']
```

Comment: You should go into detail about how that helps or how to approach it.

Comment: @Daenyth: yes, thank you - I was working on just that. I didn't want to post the code until I had it properly tested.

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) function does exactly that -- remove specific characters from the ends of a string -- but there are probably better ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said exactly what the pattern is, or what you want if there are no braces, but this will work on your example:

```
stripped = []
for x in my_data:
    m = re.search("{.*}", x)
    stripped.append(m.group if m else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = ['1:{test}', '2:{test}', '4:{1989}', '9:{test}', '']
map(lambda string: re.search(r'(?<=\{).+(?=\})', string).group(0), t)
```

Granted, this is not the most well-formatted or easiest to read of answers.  This maps an anonymous function that finds and returns what is inside the brackets to each element of the list, returning the whole list.

`(?<=...)` means "match only that has this at the beginning, but don't include it in the result

`(?=...)` means "match only that has this at the end, but don't include it in the result

`.+` means "at least one character of any kind"

Comment: `.+` means *one or more* characters of any kind

Comment: Sorry you're totally right, when fixing it up I took out "one or more"